# php regex difference

Tags: php, regex

I want to know what the difference is between these two regular expressions, what are the pro's and con's.

Example input (date) 31-12-2012.

```
Method A:
/(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/
```

And:

```
Method B:
^[0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{4}\$
```

Comment: Are you _only_ after the `\d` vs. `[0-9]` difference? Because that starting `^` in (2) anchors it at the beginning (no such thing in 1, a date somewhere in any text will match), and an ending `\$`, meaning literal `$`, not end of line (remove the \ to get that). very important distinction to me... Also, capturing (`()`) vs. non-capturing, fixed `-` delimiter or both `-` and `/` recognized as delimiter.... A LOT of differences.

Comment: B should better be `/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/` to match the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first has delimiters `/`, the second one doesn't. For now, I assume that to be a copy/paste issue.
2. B forces a date to occur as the first item in the string with `^`, A just agrees with `"a datestring anyw00-00-0000where in the string"`.
3. A captures the date in match 1 by the extra `()`, B does no such thing. As the entire match will be the `0`th item in a match, you could lose the unneeded `()`'s.
4. `\d` vs `[0-9]` -> see [Avner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293272/358679).
5. A only matches `-` as the day/month/year separator. Use that if you only expect `-`. If you expect BOTH `-` AND `/`, use `[-/]` as in B.
6. B wants the the date to end in `$`, A doesn't. Use the one which applies. If I assume this is a copy/paste error (`$` being escaped because it is in a double quoted string for no good reason), it makes B match *only* a date because of the `^regex$` anchoring, and A a date string anywhere in the input. Once again, use the option that applies to your data.
7. Neither of them validates a date. Only a format that kinda looks like one, but could as well not be one.

Answer (score 2):

Method B will accept slashes as well as dashes for the separator character. Otherwise, they are identical.

Also, be aware that Method B will accept:

`31/12-2012` or `31-12/2012`

The only con I can think of is that Method B will take up more disk space because it is a longer string.

Comment: _Otherwise, they are identical_ => really? Extra super-sure really?

Answer (score 2):

\d is pretty much identical to [0-9]. I can imagine for [0-9] there's a tiny tiny bit of more parsing involved, but this is negligible.

Then the only difference that's left is that Method B also parses:

31/12/2012

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, `\d` should catch more than just [0-9]. It should theoretically catch [۰-۹] as well (Arabic numerals), and any other numeric format that the Unicode standard includes as "digits". 
This can include ancient Greek and Roman numerals, counting rods, east-Asian characters, irrational numbers and Hexadecimal digits. [Really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode).

In practice, I think most regex parsers don't handle these properly, from the several online regex tools I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Method A will have back-reference 1 (or $1, or \1 - whatever the language is) since this regex is wrapped with ()